# Yii2-Amcharts : How can i export to image?

Tags: yii2, amcharts

I have this graph in my view
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/subac.png)

```
$chartConfiguration = [
    'type'         => 'serial',
    'dataProvider' => $datasProvider, 

   'rotate'        => false,
   'categoryField' => 'respuesta',


   'categoryAxis' => ['gridPosition' => 'start', 'axisColor' => '#DADADA'],
   'valueAxes'    => [['axisAlpha' => 0.2]],
   'graphs'       => [['type' => 'column',
                       'title' => 'Respuesta',

                       'valueField' => 'COUNT(*)',
                       'lineAlpha' => 0,
                       'fillColors' => '#BC1818',
                       'fillAlphas' => 1,
                       'balloonText' => '[[title]] in [[category]]:<b>[[value]]</b>'
                     ]],


];
echo \speixoto\amcharts\Widget::widget(['chartConfiguration' => $chartConfiguration]);
```

I know i have the these

- 'pathToImages' =>  '../to/my/route'
- 'export' => 'true'

But no one of these works and i've tried to use the library of Amcharts(export. js and export.css

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return an object in the UI for `export`:

```
"export": {
  "enabled": true
}
```

`"export": true` is not enough.

https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/intro-exporting-charts/